# Why Android BaseAdapter Click Listener not working in PullToRefreshListView?

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I want to update my listview by dragging up using PullToRefreshListView class. when i am using my own ListView BaseAdapter the Click Listener not working.

**MyCode:**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.androidsurya.pulltorefresh;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.androidsurya.customviews.PullToRefreshListView;
import com.androidsurya.customviews.PullToRefreshListView.OnRefreshListener;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private ArrayList<String> mListItems;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pulltorefresh);

    // Set a listener to be invoked when the list should be refreshed.
    ((PullToRefreshListView) getListView())
            .setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    // Do work to refresh the list here.
                    new GetDataTask().execute();
                }
            });

    mListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    mListItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(mStrings));

    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mListItems);

    MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this, mListItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Simulates a background job.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        return mStrings;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        mListItems.add(0, "Added new item after refresh...");
        // Call onRefreshComplete when the list has been refreshed.
        ((PullToRefreshListView) getListView()).onRefreshComplete();

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}

private String[] mStrings = { "Andaman and Nicobar Islands",
        "Andhra Pradesh", "Arunachal Pradesh", "Assam", "Bihar",
        "Chhattisgarh", "Goa", "Gujarat", "Haryana", "Himachal Pradesh",
        "Jammu and Kashmir", "Jharkhand", "Karnataka", "Kerala",
        "Madhya Pradesh", "Maharashtra", "Manipur" }; }
```

**MyListAdapter.java**

```
package com.androidsurya.pulltorefresh;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private ArrayList<String> list;
private Context context;
private Activity activity;

public MyListAdapter(Activity activity,Context context, ArrayList<String> list) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

    LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();


    arg1 = inflator.inflate(R.layout.test_list, null);

     TextView txt = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.list_text); 

     txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Toast.makeText(activity, "Clicked "+arg0, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    return arg1;
}
 }
```

This is the above code , which i am trying to implement txt.setOnClickListener not working.

Please let me know some possible solution.

Comment: Post `pulltorefresh.xml`

Comment: Sorry i made one mistake , i didn't mentioned the ListView in my xml , but now one more issue , txt.setOnClickListener() not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. And change your position `int arg0` to `final int arg0` just for check.

```
        arg2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("Position", "positon : " + arg0);
        }
    });
```

regards.